# Why does the execution time of my loop vary so much?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17

I have this loop I will be calculating *a lot* later on, so I am trying to optimize it as much as I can. When I run it with a rather large file (43564 atoms), the execution time varies quite dramatically: from 4.5 seconds to 18 seconds. Can I change anything to more consistently hit the 4.5 seconds?

```
std::vector<float> data(protein_atoms.size()*5);
for (size_t i = 0; i < protein_atoms.size(); i++) {
    const Atom& a = protein_atoms[i]; 
    data[5*i] = a.coords.x;
    data[5*i+1] = a.coords.y;
    data[5*i+2] = a.coords.z;
    data[5*i+3] = a.effective_charge;
    data[5*i+4] = a.occupancy;
}

cout << "Entering loop. Size: " << protein_atoms.size() << endl;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// calculate p-p distances
for (size_t i = 1; i < protein_atoms.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = i; j < protein_atoms.size(); j++) {
        double dist = sqrt(pow(data[5*i] - data[5*j], 2) + pow(data[5*i+1] - data[5*j+1], 2) + pow(data[5*i+2] - data[5*j+2], 2));
        double weight = data[5*i+3]*data[5*j+3]*data[5*i+4]*data[5*j+4]; // Z1*Z2*w1*w2
        p_pp[(int) dist/width] += 2*weight;
    }
}
p_pp[0] += protein_atoms.size();

auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop-start);
cout << "Loop took " << dur.count() << " milliseconds." << endl;
```

Comment: First this is not a [example]...

Comment: Then, make sure you're not using Windows (update background process, etc.) and/or not have CPU-heavy/memory-heavy background processes running.

Comment: Side note: The `data` representation is ultra-ugly and error-prone. Use a `struct` with descriptive member names or a `std::tuple`. The `float` and `double` manipulation looks suspicious as well; I wouldn’t fancy debugging precision losses and/or numerical stability issues on that. Last but not least, are you sure your C-style cast is doing exactly what you intended…? Double-check the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and (ideally) avoid C-style casts in C++.

Comment: You're leaving out the type of p_pp, what is it?

Comment: @user202729 I am already running it without any intensive background tasks on Ubuntu.

Comment: You do some common index calculations several times, for example, `5*i` when you are filling the `data` buffer in the beginning. Try to calculate once, and use it. You are doing the same thing on the loop below. 
It might give you some optimization if the optimizer does not do that for you.

Comment: The optimizer should be smart enough (although in this case the only way to be sure is to look at the assembly)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek The data representation is temporary but functional. I intend to remove it from the loop completely since it can be calculated outside of it. Note that it is not part of my time measurement. I am not too worried about accuracy - speed is far more important. You're right about the (int) cast though :)

Comment: @MarcStevens Sorry, I didn't notice that. It's just a vector<double>.

Comment: Ok, and it must be resize'd beforehand, so there is no potential overhead from growing the container caused by inserts.

Comment: This is a large time variation for a CPU-bound operation (or maybe cache-bound).  It has to be an external cause.  Look for things like CPU frequency scaling: the BIOS or the OS turns down the CPU speed for power savings or thermal management.  And `perf` should help confirm that there are no other tasks competing for the CPU.

Comment: Declare a pointer to `data[5 * i]` and use the pointer like an array.

Answer (score 2):

You might be exceeding cache sizes, which could make it slower.

Here are some pointer that could help speed it up:

- reduce 5 floats to 4 floats per atom by premultiplying 3rd and 4th element
- do square explicitly instead of pow(x,2)
- be more cache friendly: divide into blocks of N (small power of 2, say 256). Then have double for loop over blocks, and within a double for loop processing that block pair. You of course also need to consider all pairs within a block, so that's another separate double for loop.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::min

// alignas: make it simd friedlier
struct alignas(16) atom_helper_t {
float x,y,z;
float ec_oc;
};

float invwidth = 1.0/float(width); // precompute division

void update_pp(const std::vector<double>& p_pp, const atom_helper_t& a, const atom_helper_t& b)
{
    double dist = sqrt((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x)+(a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)+(a.z-b.z)*(a.z-b.z));
    double weight = a.ec_oc * b.ec_oc;
    p_pp[static_cast<size_t>(dist*invwidth)] += 2*weight;
}

...

// fill data from protein_atoms
std::vector<atom_helper_t> data;
data.reserve(protein_atoms.size());
for (const auto& a : protein_atoms)
    data.emplace_back({a.coords.x, a.coords.y, a.coords.z, a.effective_charge*a.occupancy});

// try different blocksizes and benchmark results
const size_t blocksize = 256;
// first for loop over blocks
for (size_t bi = 0; bi < data.size(); bi += blocksize)
{
    // compute end of block
    size_t biend = std::min<size_t>(bi+blocksize, data.size());
    // process all pairs within block
    for (size_t i = bi; i < biend; ++i)
        for (size_t j = i+1; j < biend; ++j)
            update_pp(data[i], data[j]);
    // second for loop over blocks, starting at block bi+blocksize
    for (size_t bj = bi+blocksize; bj < data.size(); bj += blocksize)
    {
        // compute end of block
        size_t bjend = std::min<size_t>(bj+blocksize, protein_atoms.size());
        // process all pairs within block bi and bj
        for (size_t i = bi; i < biend; ++i)
           for (size_t j = bj; j < bjend; ++j)
               update_pp(data[i], data[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, those are some nice suggestions. However, even if I am exceeding cache sizes, could that really make such a huge variation in the execution time? I am just really confused about how it sometimes runs in just 4 seconds, while other times it takes 17. I would expect it to be more consistent for the same input?

Comment: Without a fully reproducible example, it will be hard to find out exactly. It is also unclear what are the characteristics of your machine. For instance on my laptop I can see varying performance for large dataset operations if the CPU starts to throttle as that also affects cache and RAM performance.

Answer (score 1):

It's very important to know the functions you are using.  `pow()` calculates the power by using logarithms (actually something like `log(exp(x)*y)`, which is a very inefficient way to calculate a square.  This cannot be optimized, in case the `pow` function is not properly registered as an intrinsec function in the compiler (I'm not sure you will get this optimization, but even in that case changing that to a product is far too complex to decide it will be better for the compiler) in any case, you are changing (`1.384E9 * 2` calls to `pow()` to calculate a complex function into simple products)  this should make a good optimization.

```
for (size_t i = 1; i < protein_atoms.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = i; j < protein_atoms.size(); j++) {
        double dist = sqrt(pow(data[5*i] - data[5*j], 2) + pow(data[5*i+1] - data[5*j+1], 2) + pow(data[5*i+2] - data[5*j+2], 2));
        double weight = data[5*i+3]*data[5*j+3]*data[5*i+4]*data[5*j+4]; // Z1*Z2*w1*w2
        p_pp[(int) dist/width] += 2*weight;
    }
}
```

A good optimizing compiler will do what I'm proposing below, but the fundamental idea is to never repeat the same calculation twice (like that `5*i` or `5*j` you show)  Also knowing that you are squaring is bad use to use `pow()` as it takes the logarithm to do the power (it's better to do a simple `x*x`, instead of `pow(x, 2)`).  I should have written that code in this way:

```
size_t sz = protein_atoms.size(); // this will save a lot of size() 
                                  // calculations to get the same result
                                  // (1,384E9 times) in case the size()
                                  // method is not inlined.
for (size_t i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
    for (size_t j = i; j < sz; j++) {
        int i5 = 5*i, j5 = 5*j;
        double d0 = data[i5  ] - data[j5  ],
               d1 = data[i5+1] - data[j5+1],
               d2 = data[i5+2] - data[j5+2],
               dist = d0*d0 + d1*d1 + d2*d2,
               d3 = data[i5+3] - data[j5+3],
               d4 = data[i5+4] - data[j5+4],
               weight2 = 2*d3*d3*d4*d4; // included the 2 factor here.
        p_pp[(int) dist/width] += weight2;
    }
}
```

BTW, I don't understand why you cast the value of `dist` to an `int`, as it will be converted to `double` when dividing by `width` to calculate the `p_pp` index.  Shouldn't you mean `(int) dist / (int) width`? (to make integer division) or in the opposite, you meant `(int)(dist / width)`? (to convert the result to `int`--- unnecessary, as it is done by the language)
Remember that `(int)` has more precedence than `/`.

Finally, I have assumed what you write is what you want to do, but I'm not sure you are doing well by incrementing `i` and `j` by one at each loop iteration.  I'm more in the idea that you want to add `5` each time, with expressions like `i += 5` and `j += 5`.

A good compiler should do all these optimizations by itself (and probably more, like unrolling the loop somehow, to avoid jumps) and you probably could get more speed by multithreading it (some compilers do) and making loop iterations to be done by different threads, so you can benefit of having several cores for the computation.

## Final note

Get used to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as I have not been able to test your code.  This is very important, as I have not been able to reproduce (and measure) the time savings by myself, because your code couldn't be executed locally to test.